# Switching between MySQL and SQLite3 in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I am working on a project in Mercurial that uses Django. In the code (under `settings.py`) there is:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'foo',
    'USER': 'bar',
    'PASSWORD': 'baz',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB;' },
    }
}

#Use a local mysql db for development
if IN_DEVELOPMENT:
    DATABASES["default"] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'bar',
        'PASSWORD': 'baz',
        'HOST': '',
        'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB;' },
        }
```

I was told I could simply replace the `mysql` in the `if IN_DEVELOPMENT` block with `sqlite3` (as I do not have mySQL and my attempts at installing it have been unsuccessful).  This leads to an error when I load *any* page, which I was able to resolve by commenting out the second `OPTIONS` line.  Now I am able to load pages that rely solely on static data.  But when I try to access a table, I get [errors like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stPk8.jpg) (though the name of the "no such table" varies).

Do I have to recreate the database tables from the project?  Is there an `init_command` (which I presume creates the tables if they don't already exist?) I can use with `sqlite3`?  Do I have any course of action other than downloading `MySQL-python` (and would that even help?)

Comment: dont post dropbox links ... since they are behind a login

Comment: Sorry, thank you.  Updated link

Comment: try deleting the file `foo`... I think django will auto rebuild your tables only if the database does not already exist (or you might need to run `admin.py syncdb` or whatever (I dont use django enough clearly)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you need to create the tables, since they don't exist in the new database. You do that in exactly the same way as you did originally: by running `manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with lodadata session.

https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata

and this gave me the solution.

"
To fix this problem, make sure to backup the database by excluding contenttypes and auth.permissions tables
./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
"
it works for me.